# How do I change owner/permissions of auto mount on an embedded Linaro based Linux?

Tags: linux, mount

I have an ARM based embedded system that when it auto mounts a USB drive it mounts it as follows:

```
drwx------ 6 linaro linaro 2048 Jan 1 1970 PENDRIVE
```

I need to change the permissions and possibly the owner of the drive automatically as it is mounted by automount.

My system is:

```
Linux Marsmpd 3.0.36-t3+ #19 PREEMPT Mon Aug 6 12:10:13 EST 2012 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

How do I accomplish this?

Also, is there a way to run a script automatically when a drive is automounted?